# Is it possible to use Argon2id hashes with PAM?

Tags: password-management, bcrypt, pbkdf2, argon2, pam

I was wondering if it's possible to implement more secure KDF like bcrypt, scrypt, pbkdf2 and argon2id in PAM authentication.

Ideally I would like to have their hashes instead of SHA-512 ones directly in /etc/shadow, but we all know what Ulrich Drepper wrote about bcrypt 13 years ago. OpenSUSE and OpenBSD seems to use a patched `glibc`, but other distro don't like the idea to implement these patches.

https://access.redhat.com/articles/1519843

Neither `libgcrypt` seems to support Argon2id; GRUB2 maintainers were against bundling the KDF in the bootloader when they introduced [LUKS2 support](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/commit/?id=365e0cc3e7e44151c14dd29514c2f870b49f9755) in early 2020

Comment: You may need a custom solution for implementing this.

Comment: What did Ulrich Drepper write about bcrypt -13- 16 years ago?

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/articles/1519843